# Drop external event on resource list item fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am working on react-fullcalendar with resource view.
My requirement is I want to drop event on resource list , I am able to drop event on day, week and month calendar successfully.
[image]

Please help me to find way to drop event on resource name.( I have event with pre-define time so when I tried to drop event on resource, just that resource Id should get attached to it and it would display on calendar with my pre-define start and end time.

Comment: "I have event with pre-define time so when I tried to drop event on resource"...that's not how the calendar functionality works. You have to drop it on a specific time within the resource, you can't just drop it on a resource. If you want this then you'll have to use your own custom code to add a dropzone on the names, handle that and have code to then add the event to the calendar with the resource ID specified.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for reply. Could you please help me to know how to do this customization. It would be great help if you provide me any example through which I get the idea of required customization.

Comment: I don't know specifically, where are you stuck with the idea? You should be able to find tutorials/examples/documentation about libraries which offer drag and drop functionality. Then you can use fullCalendar's resource rendering hooks to make the resource names into drop zones. Make some attempt and then ask if you're stuck. I don't have some ready made example to give you myself.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution? Or it still requires writing a plugin from scratch? 
 I sincerely don't understand why developers of this framework decided not to git with api (it would be not that difficult, we just need resource id, dropped item and calendar api at one context after drop event on resource title). Because of that our client right now is looking for another solution like DevExtreme or MobiScroll.